# How do i format the x-labels correctly in this simple stockchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is my https://jsfiddle.net/rmv78z45/1/

I am simply trying to display the Dates correctly on the x-axis in a format YYYY-MM-DD

I have tried setting `xAxis: datetime` but it just breaks the chart.
Try it in jsfiddle.

The x-axis hover is showing correctly `2019-01-01, 2019-01-02` but the x-axis is starts with `1-Jan` and then `00:00:00:001, ..002, 003` etc.

Answer (score 1):

i managed to solve this differently by mapping 
Data.parse on the first column

```
dat1 = [["2019-01-01", 0],["2019-01-02",2],["2019-01-03", 5],["2019-01-04",10]];

dat1 = dat1.map(([date,L]) => [Date.parse(date), L]);
```

this way it recognizes the date nicely.

i had another issue with such a formatted JSON array:

```
dat2 = [{"date":"2018-05-25","L":"3"},{"date":"2018-06-01","L":"2"},{"date":"2018-06-08","L":"2"},{"date":"2018-06-15","L":"3"}];
dat2 = dat2.map(({date,L}) => [date, L]);
dat2 = dat2.map(([date,L]) => [Date.parse(date), parseInt(L) ]);
```

i solved that using the parseInt() and Date.parse(date) as well!

works now perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The Date should be a UTC timestamp so you can use the Date constructor with [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) (which, returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch) as the first index in each data array you will be good to go.

For example:

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: [
      [new Date("2019-01-01").getTime(), 0],
      [new Date("2019-01-02").getTime(), 2],
      [new Date("2019-01-03").getTime(), 5],
      [new Date("2019-01-04").getTime(), 10]
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 800px"></div>
```